# Get active connected IPs to server

Tags: php, nginx, download

I'm serving downloads from my server and I need to know if it is possible to get the connected clients and look if their download is still in progress.

So is it possible to get a list of outgoing connections, for example like iptraf, just in PHP or so?

If not, how is it possible look it up on Linux, like iptraf is doing it?

My server system is, debian with nginx.